# Convert json result to PHP

Tags: php, json

In my example I have 2 pages.
What I basically want is to pass some data (or not like in this example) with JSON to PHP. In PHP I query a select statement and pass that data back to my index page.

Now that all goes well, but then I want the returned data showed in different div's.

My index page:

```
function toonProfiel(){
  $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "./query/getmijnprofiel.php",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function ( response ) {
    alert( response.a);
  }
  });
}
```

In this example 'a' get's alerted! All is working fine!

My getmijnprofielphp page:

```
<?php

session_start ();

require '../php/connect.php';

$id = $_SESSION['id'];

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT a, b FROM leden WHERE userid=?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($a, $b);

    /* fetch value */
    $stmt->fetch();

    $response = array(
      'a' => $a,
      'b' => $b,
    );

    echo json_encode( $response );

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

But what I want is the following:

```
<div class="diva">
  <label>a:</label>
  <span><?php if ($a!= "") { echo $a; } ?></span>
</div>
```

I know the returned data isn't a PHP variable so this doesn't work, but how can I show the returned variable 'a' in my div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your success message as

```
$(".diva span").html(response.a);
```

This will change HTML at runtime using jQuery. I also suggest to put some ID on span and use that instead of generic class.

Comment: Thanks! That works nicely...
Is it ok if I use this for about 20 returned values, or is there a better way then?

And just one more thing, if 'a' is empty, I want to show the text "Niet ingevuld".

How can I make that happen?

Comment: you can use it for as many field as you want, however you have to give id to al teast parent and then use relative path to select them. you can put check like if(response.a =="") or whatever way you want to put check or change value. but I suggest to do that in your PHP or SQL itself for little better code in all.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give every element an ID...

And I'll do the 'Niet ingevuld' thing in PHP indeed.
Thanks again! Sorry I can't upvote you...

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="diva">
  <label>a:</label>
  <span id="response"></span>
</div>
```

you need to add the data you receive to the dom using javascript as well:

```
document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = response.a;
```